# Ruby on Rails - Render new on show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested resources and I'm trying to show the new layout for the nested resource on the show of the parent.

```
resources :discussions do
    resources :comments
end
```

**discussions\show.html.erb**

```
<%= @discussion.title %>
<%= ... render the discussion %>
<%= ... render the existing comments %>
<% render 'comments/new' %>    <--- trying something like this
```

`comments/new` throws an error because it's missing the partial. 
`comments/form` works to get past that, but throws an error saying my `@comment` is `nil`.

**comments/_form.html.erb**

`undefined method discussion for nil:NilClass`

`<%= bootstrap_form_for([ @comment.discussion, @comment] ) do |f| %>`

Do I have to change something in the controller, or am I going about this incorrectly?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**discussions\show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @discussion.comments.build %>
```

**comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([ comment.discussion, comment] ) do |f| %>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I updated your answer, as there was a few changes I had to make but it works like that. Thank you. :)